# DELETE with subquery and LIKE

Tags: mysql

how to delete rows with query like this

```
DELETE FROM tbl
WHERE title LIKE CONCAT((select title from tbl where id = 10),'%')
```

this query return error

> [Err] 1093 - You can't specify target table 'entries' for update in
>   FROM clause

Comment: how many values is ur SELECT returning.. ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DELETE t
FROM 
    tableX AS t
  JOIN
    ( SELECT CONCAT(title, '%') AS titleL
      FROM tableX
      WHERE id = 10
    ) AS ti
    ON t.title LIKE ti.titleL
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to get around that error is to break it up into 2 separate statements.

You can select the title you're looking to match on into a user-defined variable and then do the delete.

Like this:

```
SELECT title
INTO @title
FROM tbl 
WHERE id = 10;

DELETE FROM tbl
WHERE title LIKE CONCAT(@title,'%');
```

Comment: Note that in MySQL Workbench the following syntax is needed for the SELECT query:




SELECT @title := title
FROM tbl 
WHERE id = 10;

Answer (score 1):

I think you just got to insert another from line in order to execute a selection query:

```
DELETE t1
FROM tbl as t1
WHERE t1.title LIKE CONCAT((select title from tbl as t2 where t2.id = 10),'%')
```

Comment: This doesn't work for the same reason that OP's query doesn't work.

Comment: updated the query, forgot the as thing, it's a little simpler than the join

Answer (score 1):

You need something like:

```
DELETE tbl
  FROM tbl T1
       INNER JOIN (SELECT title FROM tbl WHERE id = 10) T2                   
    ON T1.title LIKE CONCAT(T2.title, '%')
```

Comment: same error ... [Err] 1093 - You can't specify target table 'entries' for update in FROM clause